# How to force sleep after a timeout regardless of app?

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s-5, standby

I'm letting my little kid use an old Android phone (Galaxy S5) as a camera. I've got the camera app pinned so he can't do anything except take pics. He hits Home to wake it up and then can tap the screen to take pics to his heart's content.

The problem is that the camera app keeps the phone awake and screen on, bypassing whatever the phone's global options are. Apparently the screen stays on forever, too. I'd like it to have a normal timeout so kiddo doesn't need to remember to hit the power button. (Worst thing in the world for him is to have him pick up his 'camera' only to find it has a dead battery, right?)

Unfortunately there's no option in the Samsung camera app to change this. The system sleep setting is ignored. I tried a few apps that will auto-change screen timeouts based on app, but it has no effect - the camera app overrides this. I tried a couple other camera apps, but they have the same result. Anyway I like the Samsung camera - it's really easy for my kid to manage.

How can I force this phone to go to sleep after x seconds of inactivity, even when a camera app is running?

Is this a job for Tasker? (I haven't tried that yet - really complex app last I messed with it.)

Comment: [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) is a simple automation app. Try if it works. Trigger: app Launched > camera Action 1. Wait xx minutes/ second 2.screen off

Comment: Sorry action 2 should be set screen time out. Guess your phone isn't rooted, to think of other ways to override